# Shopify Liquid - Keep Anouncement Bar Closed

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I have created a custom Announcement Bar with a Close Button on our Shopify Website.
The following script code closes the bar:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

if ($('.announcement-bar').length){

$( '.x' ).click(function() {
    $(".announcement-bar").remove();
    $("body").addClass("no-announcement-bar");
});
}
});
</script>
```

Problem is I need it to stay closed if the user decides to refresh the page, or open other pages on the website. The Announcement Bar keeps coming back up.
And I want to implement a theme setting checkbox something like:

```
{%- if section.settings.show_everytime == false -%}
then don't show the bar after close
{%- else -%}
show bar everytime
```

I have an idea how to implement this, but don't know how to do the script to manage the click event with this If statement.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The idea your presented is not going to work due to 2 reasons.

1. Liquid is a server side templating language and you cannot re-render it after some user interaction. Like after closing Announcement bar in your scenario.
2. Theme settings are global and for option configurations fro admin. You cannot save the end user preferences in your theme settings.

> {%- if section.settings.show_everytime == false -%}

This will not show the announcement section for any user.

So now a possible solution is to save information on client side, that will be the browser in this case. You can use browser storage or cookies.

Example code using Local Storage

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.announcement-bar').length) {

        if (localStorage.getItem('barDismissed')) {
            $(".announcement-bar").remove();
            $("body").addClass("no-announcement-bar");
        } else {
            $('.x').click(function() {
                $(".announcement-bar").remove();
                $("body").addClass("no-announcement-bar");
                localStorage.setItem('barDismissed', true);
            });  
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

This checks if **barDismissed** property exists in [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), then hide the Announcement bar. If not then show the announcement bar and if user closes, then save the preference.

You can adjust the code to use [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies).

Comment: Thank you so much for the sample.
There is, however, a Notice Header in our theme (which we don't use, due to limitations) that has the option "Never Display Again If Closed". For the life of me, I cannot find the code that they used to handle this.
I will try your sample code and get back to you.

Comment: That may only be an option that theme developer uses to output required JS. Something like I mentioned above. The related JS code may be in minfied theme JS file.

Comment: So for example, am I able to use an If statement like `{%- if section.settings.show_everytime  == false -%}` to do first half of the `<script>` before `else`? and then `{%- elsif -%}` for second half of `<script>` after `else`?

Comment: No.. You can only use them to output required JS code in script. The actual hide and show would be done using JavaScript. For example, you can use `{%- if section.settings.show_everytime  == false -%}` this to output JS that will handle the dismiss logic. First if condition above in my code.

Comment: Cool, will try and report back to you. Thanx for the help.

Comment: The announcement bar also has a free shipping calculator now, but how do I go about updating the text without refreshing the current page a customer is on? For example, just like the Cart updates how many items are in it without needing to refresh the page, how do I do the same for the announcement bar?
What I believe need to happen is the Announcement Bar needs to listen to Cart update and then update itself....??

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the following code. WARNING: Might be a bit messy, lol.
Within my Announcement-Bar.liquid file, just before `{% shema %}`:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

{%- if section.settings.show_again == true -%}
   <script>
     $( document ).ready(function() {

     if ($('.announcement-bar').length){

       $( '.x' ).click(function() {
       $(".announcement-bar").remove();
       $("body").addClass("no-announcement-bar");
      });
     }
    });
   </script>
{%- else -%}
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.announcement-bar').length) {

    if (localStorage.getItem('barDismissed')) {
        $(".announcement-bar").remove();
        $("body").addClass("no-announcement-bar");
    } else {
        $('.x').click(function() {
            $(".announcement-bar").remove();
            $("body").addClass("no-announcement-bar");
            localStorage.setItem('barDismissed', true);
        });  
       }
      }
     });
    </script>
  {%- endif -%}
```

Any tips on how to maybe make the

```
localStorage.setItem('barDismissed', true);
```

expire after a certain amount of time, or maybe using cookies?
How would I implement this?

I have tried replacing localStorage to Cookies, but to now avail.
Or maybe force the announcement when a change is made. The reason for this, is we might give important notice info on the Announcement and need to have visitors see this info.

Or would it be easier to create a minimize button, to not fully close the bar, but instead just minimize it, so visitors can open it again?

Thoughts, please.

Comment: Bump... I should've used sessionStorage instead of localStorage. My bad...